# TFS Build - Publish WPF and Package Web

Tags: .net, tfs, msbuild

I have a solution that contains both a WPF project and a Web Application. I also have a TFS build definition that builds the solution when changes are checked in to source control.

I know that I can add msbuild arguments to the build definition that will either publish the WPF project (as a clickonce project to a designated folder) OR package/deploy the Web application.

The problem is that I can't seem to do both. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2012, I don't believe this is possible with the default templates. You can however [modify the build template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or create a custom one with the workflow you need for this situation.

If you are using TFS 2013, you can call a [post build Powershell script](http://blog.nwcadence.com/whats-new-in-tfs-2013-team-builds-are-able-to-run-in-powershell/) right from the definition to handle deploying the various projects built.